# Facebook Unity SDK Blank Perm Window

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-unity-sdk

So after I enter in my Facebook login info occasionally I get a weird white window instead of the normal white perm window on my android device.  Here is a screen shot of what it looks like.  Not sure what is going on, since the Facebook plugin I'm assuming has control of the activity at that time. [image]

Comment: need more detail.Is this your app? You want to log in facebook using your app? if so you have to set  your app in developers.facebook.com.

Comment: Yes, its setup on developers.facebook.com.  I know the login works because, if I repeatedly try logging in and closing the white window, the proper perm window will eventually show and allow me to accept perms and proceed with login.

Comment: I guess it's a temp issue caused by network or else.